# If the Giant Global Graph is implemented, how to search?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, linked-data, knowledge-graph

Different from knowledge graph, semantic data is decentralized. Does this mean that each search takes a lot of time to download semantic data? Does the search service require a lot of storage and memory space?

Comment: yes, the idea was to have search-engines that crawl (and cache) the semantic web (just like Google crawls the normal web). However, adoption has been lacking....